# Jupyter notebook kernel keeps dying when I run the following import statements

Tags: python, pytorch, jupyter

I am running this statement and my kernel is dying. What import might be causing this?

```
# Import our model
from model import MVP, LSTM_MVP

# Libraries for the data
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Get the sector tickers
from sector import *

# Process the data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# device = torch.device('cpu')  # CPU
```

Comment: Have you tried one by one?